# Mocking a Go database SDK

Tags: go, mocking

I am attempting to create a wrapper for test emulating around the [Go Flex SDK for Google Cloud Datastore](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/datastore). While I am currently successfully running the localhost emulator using

```
gcloud beta emulators datastore start --no-store-on-disk
```

in a separate terminal from my testing window, I would prefer to create a mock database emulator that runs as part of the test process itself (without `exec`ing the above) so that I can run multiple tests in parallel, each with its own database emulator.

I have run into a problem with the Google SDK not implementing my interface.

My wrapper contains this code:

```
package google

import (
    "context"

    "cloud.google.com/go/datastore"
)

type (
    // Datastore is a wrapper for the Google Cloud Datastore Client.
    Datastore datastore.Client

    // Datastorer represents things that can operate like a datastore.Client.
    Datastorer interface {
        Delete(context.Context, *datastore.Key) error
        Get(context.Context, *datastore.Key, interface{}) error
        GetAll(context.Context, *datastore.Query, interface{}) ([]*datastore.Key, error)
        Put(context.Context, *datastore.Key, interface{}) (*datastore.Key, error)
        PutMulti(context.Context, []*datastore.Key, interface{}) ([]*datastore.Key, error)
        RunInTransaction(context.Context, func(Transactioner) error, ...datastore.TransactionOption) (*datastore.Commit, error)
    }

    // Transactioner represents things that can operate like a datastore.Transaction.
    Transactioner interface {
        Commit() (*datastore.Commit, error)
        Delete(*datastore.Key) error
        DeleteMulti([]*datastore.Key) error
        Get(*datastore.Key, interface{}) error
        GetMulti([]*datastore.Key, interface{}) error
        Put(*datastore.Key, interface{}) (*datastore.PendingKey, error)
        PutMulti([]*datastore.Key, interface{}) ([]*datastore.PendingKey, error)
        Rollback() error
    }
)

// Delete deletes the entity for the given key.
func (d *Datastore) Delete(ctx context.Context, key *datastore.Key) error {
    return (*datastore.Client)(d).Delete(ctx, key)
}

// Get retrieves the entity for the given key.
func (d *Datastore) Get(ctx context.Context, key *datastore.Key, dst interface{}) error {
    return (*datastore.Client)(d).Get(ctx, key, dst)
}

// GetAll retrieves all entities for the given query.
func (d *Datastore) GetAll(ctx context.Context, q *datastore.Query, dst interface{}) ([]*datastore.Key, error) {
    return (*datastore.Client)(d).GetAll(ctx, q, dst)
}

// Put stores an entity for the given key.
func (d *Datastore) Put(ctx context.Context, key *datastore.Key, src interface{}) (*datastore.Key, error) {
    return (*datastore.Client)(d).Put(ctx, key, src)
}

// PutMulti is a batch version of Put.
func (d *Datastore) PutMulti(ctx context.Context, keys []*datastore.Key, src interface{}) ([]*datastore.Key, error) {
    return (*datastore.Client)(d).PutMulti(ctx, keys, src)
}

// RunInTransaction runs the given function in a transaction.
func (d *Datastore) RunInTransaction(ctx context.Context, f func(tx Transactioner) error, opts ...datastore.TransactionOption) (*datastore.Commit, error) {
    return (*datastore.Client)(d).RunInTransaction(ctx, func(t *datastore.Transaction) error {
        return f(t)
    }, opts...)
}
```

Note that these interfaces do not emulate the complete SDK. I am only including functions that I actually call in my code. I'll add new ones as needed later.

When I try to use an instance of `*datastore.Client` as a `Datastorer`, I get the following error:

```
cannot use client (type *"cloud.google.com/go/datastore".Client) as type Datastorer in field value:
    *"cloud.google.com/go/datastore".Client does not implement Datastorer (wrong type for RunInTransaction method)
        have RunInTransaction(context.Context, func(*"cloud.google.com/go/datastore".Transaction) error, ..."cloud.google.com/go/datastore".TransactionOption) (*"cloud.google.com/go/datastore".Commit, error)
        want RunInTransaction(context.Context, func(Transactioner) error, ..."cloud.google.com/go/datastore".TransactionOption) (*"cloud.google.com/go/datastore".Commit, error)
```

because `*datastore.Client` requires a function that takes a `func(*datastore.Transaction) error` and my interface wants a `func(Transactioner) error`.

Is there any way to change this so that it compiles?

If I can get it working, I plan to create types that implement my `Datastorer` and `Transactioner` interfaces and use maps to mock the real database. As far as tranactions go, for testing I can use `sync.Mutex` if I need them, but since each test is a single thread and will get its own database object, I may not need to lock them.

Comment: One way to solve this is to have a mediator between the interface and the implementation, basically a thin wrapper that implements the interface that you want to use and then passes the correct types to the underlying concrete type. E.g.; somthing that takes a `Transactioner`, converts it to `*datastore.Transaction`, and then passes it to `*datastore.Client`.

Comment: That is what I'm realizing. I've made some progress, but am running into new problems with the `datastore.Query` type. If I find a complete solution, I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've gotten it to compile by using this code:

```
package google

import (
    "context"

    "cloud.google.com/go/datastore"
)

type (
    // Datastore is a wrapper for the Google Cloud Datastore Client.
    Datastore struct {
        *datastore.Client
    }

    // Datastorer represents things that can operate like a datastore.Client.
    Datastorer interface {
        Delete(context.Context, *datastore.Key) error
        Get(context.Context, *datastore.Key, interface{}) error
        GetAll(context.Context, interface{}, interface{}) ([]*datastore.Key, error)
        Put(context.Context, *datastore.Key, interface{}) (*datastore.Key, error)
        PutMulti(context.Context, []*datastore.Key, interface{}) ([]*datastore.Key, error)
        RunInTransaction(context.Context, func(Transactioner) error, ...datastore.TransactionOption) (*datastore.Commit, error)
    }

    // Querier represents things that can operate like a datastore.Query.
    Querier interface {
        Filter(string, interface{}) Querier
    }

    // Transactioner represents things that can operate like a datastore.Transaction.
    Transactioner interface {
        Commit() (*datastore.Commit, error)
        Delete(*datastore.Key) error
        DeleteMulti([]*datastore.Key) error
        Get(*datastore.Key, interface{}) error
        GetMulti([]*datastore.Key, interface{}) error
        Put(*datastore.Key, interface{}) (*datastore.PendingKey, error)
        PutMulti([]*datastore.Key, interface{}) ([]*datastore.PendingKey, error)
        Rollback() error
    }
)

// Delete deletes the entity for the given key.
func (d *Datastore) Delete(ctx context.Context, key *datastore.Key) error {
    return d.Client.Delete(ctx, key)
}

// Get retrieves the entity for the given key.
func (d *Datastore) Get(ctx context.Context, key *datastore.Key, dst interface{}) error {
    return d.Client.Get(ctx, key, dst)
}

// GetAll retrieves all entities for the given query.
func (d *Datastore) GetAll(ctx context.Context, q interface{}, dst interface{}) ([]*datastore.Key, error) {
    return d.Client.GetAll(ctx, q.(*datastore.Query), dst)
}

// Put stores an entity for the given key.
func (d *Datastore) Put(ctx context.Context, key *datastore.Key, src interface{}) (*datastore.Key, error) {
    return d.Client.Put(ctx, key, src)
}

// PutMulti is a batch version of Put.
func (d *Datastore) PutMulti(ctx context.Context, keys []*datastore.Key, src interface{}) ([]*datastore.Key, error) {
    return d.Client.PutMulti(ctx, keys, src)
}

// RunInTransaction runs the given function in a transaction.
func (d *Datastore) RunInTransaction(ctx context.Context, f func(tx Transactioner) error, opts ...datastore.TransactionOption) (*datastore.Commit, error) {
    return d.Client.RunInTransaction(ctx, func(t *datastore.Transaction) error {
        return f(t)
    }, opts...)
}
```

I changed `DataStore` to a `struct` containing the `datastore.Client` and added a new interface `Querier` that contains the functions that I am using from `datastore.Query`. I also updated `GetAll` to accept an `interface{}` instead of a `*datastore.Query` and then type-assert it to be a `*datastore.Query`. I cannot have it accept a `Querier` because then I cannot pass variables of type `*datastore.Query` because they do not satisfy the `Querier` interface (`Filter` returns a `Querier` instead of a `*datastore.Query`).

All existing tests using the emulator running in a separate process are passing.

**UPDATE**:

I changed `Datastore` to

```
Datastore datastore.Client
```

and added a wrapper `Query` around `datastore.Query`:

```
Query datastore.Query
```

Now, the `Datastorer` interface contains

```
GetAll(context.Context, Querier, interface{}) ([]*datastore.Key, error)
```

and the `GetAll` function is defined as

```
func (d *Datastore) GetAll(ctx context.Context, q Querier, dst interface{}) ([]*datastore.Key, error) {
    return (*datastore.Client)(d).GetAll(ctx, (*datastore.Query)(q.(*Query)), dst)
}
```

and `Query.Filter` is defined as

```
func (q *Query) Filter(filterStr string, value interface{}) Querier {
    return (*Query)((*datastore.Query)(q).Filter(filterStr, value))
}
```

In calling code, I use

```
q := datastore.NewQuery(entity).Filter("Deleted =", false)
_, err := r.client.GetAll(ctx, (*Query)(q), data)
```

This compiles and all tests are passing.

Comment: Might be better to use `Querier` instead of `interface{}`, then have another type, let's say `DSQuery` that implements `Querier` and wraps around `*datastore.Query`, then you can get rid of type assertions and it's easy to then add and use Fake/Stub/Mock `Querier` implementations.

Comment: last suggestion: Also wrap the constructor so that you don't have to do `(*Query)(q)` every time you want to pass a `Querier` to func. [simplified example](https://play.golang.org/p/Pql9bhJLUE)

Answer (score 1):

I know that question has been asked a long time ago but in case one still may wondering how to Mock Google Datastore Client and Transaction here is a snapshot of how I got it to work.

```
type Client interface {
    Get(ctx context.Context, key *datastore.Key, dst interface{}) (err error)
    NewTransaction(ctx context.Context, opts ...datastore.TransactionOption) (t Transaction, err error)
    Put(ctx context.Context, key *datastore.Key, src interface{}) (*datastore.Key, error)
}

type Transaction interface {
    Commit() (c *datastore.Commit, err error)
    Rollback() (err error)
    Get(key *datastore.Key, dst interface{}) (err error)
    Put(key *datastore.Key, src interface{}) (*datastore.PendingKey, error)
    Delete(key *datastore.Key) error
}

type Datastore struct {
    *datastore.Client
}

func (d *Datastore) NewTransaction(ctx context.Context, opts ...datastore.TransactionOption) (t Transaction, err error) {
    return d.Client.NewTransaction(ctx, opts...)
}
```

Of course, If you are using different method against Datastore it's up to you to implement them.

In my tests, I can now Mock Datastore Client and Transaction like :

```
mockedClient := mock_gcloud.NewMockClient(ctrl)
mockedTransaction := mock_gcloud.NewMockTransaction(ctrl)
...
mockedClient.EXPECT().NewTransaction(context.Background()).Return(mockedTransaction, nil).Times(1)
```

Et voilà.

Comment: Thanks for this :)